# React: Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Bootcamp student here. I am working on a little personal project for fun but I keep encountering this error. I've checked my import and exports for these files and everything looks correct. What else could possibly be causing this error?

Error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

```
App.js file 
import "./styles.css";
import React from 'react'
import { Main } from './main.js'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      </Main>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

entire project [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-curie-ktywi).
My goal for the project is commented in *app.js*

Comment: Change  from </Main> to <Main />

Answer (score 1):

The fix is the way you are importing main, `import Main from './main.js'` as you are exporting it as a default. you are not exporting an object

```
App.js file 
import "./styles.css";
import React from 'react'
import Main from './main.js'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Main/>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You may also need to add a render method to your Main class.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import SUBJECT from "./subject";
import GENRE from "./genre";

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      subject: SUBJECT,
      genre: GENRE
    };
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  };
}

export default Main;
```